# drag and drop to contenteditable element second and subsequent lines

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, contenteditable

I want to drag and drop the tag to the `contenteditable="true"` element string using html5 and javascript.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  function dragStartFromPalette(event){
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/html",
    '<original-element class="draggable_element">'+this.innerHTML+'</original-element>');
  }
  function dragEndFromPalette(event){
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copyMove";
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  var light_tags = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable_element');
  for(i = 0; i < light_tags.length; i++){
    light_tags[i].addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartFromPalette);
    light_tags[i].addEventListener('dragend', dragEndFromPalette);
  };
}, false);
</script>

<style>
.draggable_element {
  background-color: rgb(251, 214, 132);
}
</style>

<original-element class="draggable_element" draggable="true">Lorem</original-element>
<original-element class="draggable_element" draggable="true">ipsum</original-element>
<original-element class="draggable_element" draggable="true">dolor</original-element>

<div contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, illum reiciendis quas in quam eos iste inventore. Perferendis amet vel, ratione unde rerum? Quasi ea maxime incidunt, perferendis vero. Nesciunt.</div>
```

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/uzLb5xx0/

The first line will success. however, attempting to trying drag and drop to the second and subsequent lines will insert unrelated `span` element.

How can I insert all the elements as desired? help me ;(